# Python3: error while installing google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install `google.colab` using `pip3` but I get an error as shown below:

```
pip3 install google.colab
```

I get many errors. This the last one

```
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I./pandas/_libs -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c pandas/_libs/algos.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.9/pandas/_libs/algos.o -Wno-unused-function
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pandas
  Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas-1.2.0.dist-info/
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/~andas-1.2.0.dist-info
  Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/~andas
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/n2/_qs_f40s0zdgw6wn2jj0k9zw0000gn/T/pip-install-kr44vor6/pandas/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/n2/_qs_f40s0zdgw6wn2jj0k9zw0000gn/T/pip-install-kr44vor6/pandas/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/n2/_qs_f40s0zdgw6wn2jj0k9zw0000gn/T/pip-record-hp7azct5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/pandas Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You need to install the Xcode command line tools. Typing `gcc` in your command line should give you a dialog explaining how to do this.

Comment: Could you edit the tags to colab instead of python. this is not a python specific issue.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have installed xcode but it returns the same error

Comment: @emax If that’s the case then something went wrong with the Xcode installation. Try running `xcode-select -p` and see if that path actually exists. Try [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341536/2392). If all else fails, remove Xcode completely and reinstall it from scratch, following the official Apple instructions on how to do so.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I get the following `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Answer (score 0):

It's not python related issue.
You need to install xcode

```
xcode-select --install
```

Good luck

Comment: It does not depend on that. I have installed xcode but it returns the same error